# Mechansim of reaction between 1‐bromo‐2‐fluorobenzene and furan in the presence of Li/Hg

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, halides

#### Problem

From FITJEE AITS test series:

> What is the mechanism of the following reaction?
>
> [image: reaction between 1‐bromo‐2‐fluorobenzene and furan in the presence of Li/Hg]

#### Solution

> [image: Answer]

#### My approach

It looks like Birch reduction with $\ce{Li}$ converting to $\ce{Li+}.$ But I can't make anything much out it.

Maybe there's a typo given in solution because $\ce{Br}$ and $\ce{F}$ should be present initially, or do they get removed by any means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing against Safdar, but this is technically not a two-step reaction. When lithium amalgam is added to 2-bromofluorobenzene in presence of furan, the reaction goes directly to the product, a Deals-Alder adduct:

[image: The first Diels–Alder reaction of benzyne]

However, in the absence of furan, the reaction proceeds to give biphenylene and triphenylene (Ref.1&2). The tentative reaction mechanism can be as follows:

[image: The tentative reaction mechanism]

**History:** During their investigation on the reaction of sodium with boiling chlorobenzene (a Wurtz–Fittig reaction), Bachmann and Clarke at the Eastman Kodak Co. were the first to propose benzyne ($\ce{C6H4}$) as a reactive intermediate (Ref.3). Further advances were made when it was discovered that benzyne could be generated from *ortho*-dihalobenzenes (e.g., 2-bromofluorobenzene) with lithium amalgam (Ref.1) or by forming the Grignard reagent with magnesium (Ref.4&5). The **first Diels–Alder reaction of benzyne**, with furan, was performed in this manner, giving a 76% yield of the DA-adduct, which was converted to 1-naphthol with acid (Ref.1). In the absence of the furan trapping agent, biphenylene and triphenylene were obtained in yields of 24 and 3%, respectively (Ref.2).

The halogen-lithium exchange followed by Diels–Alder reaction in one-pot has been studied recently (Ref.6):

[image: DA-Adducts via benzyne]

**References:**

1. G. Wittig, Liselotte Pohmer, “Intermediäre Bildung von Dehydrobenzol (Cyclohexa‐dienin),” *Angew. Chem.* **1955**, *67(13)*, 348-348 (https://doi.org/10.1002/ange.19550671306).
2. Curt Wentrup, “The Benzyne Story,” *J. Aust. Chem. Soc.* **2010**, 63(7), 979–986 (https://doi.org/10.1071/CH10179).
3. W. E. Bachmann, H. T. Clarke, “The Mechanism of the Wurtz-Fittig Reaction,” *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1927**, *49(8)*, 2089-2098 (https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01407a038).
4. Harry Heaney, Frederick G. Mann, Ian T. Millar, “781. The reaction of o-bromoiodobenzene with magnesium and lithium,” *J. Chem. Soc.* **1957**, 3930-3938 (https://doi.org/10.1039/JR9570003930).
5. Georg Wittig, Erhard Knauss, “Dehydrobenzol und Cyclopentadien,” *Chem. Ber.* *1958*, *91(4)*, 895-907 (https://doi.org/10.1002/cber.19580910502).
6. Shohei Eda, Toshiyuki Hamura, “Selective Halogen-Lithium Exchange of 1,2-Dihaloarenes for Successive [2+4] Cycloadditions of Arynes and Isobenzofurans,” *Molecules* **2015**, *20(10)*, 19449-19462 (https://doi.org/10.3390/molecules201019449).

Comment: Why would Li attack Br first? In the rate determining step F- is a poor leaving group so reaction should be slower if Br is attacked first. I know that C F bond is much stronger than C Br bond so which halogen will be attacked first? Also would rate be faster if both substituents were Br?

Answer (score 9):

This is a question based on two reactions.

The first reaction is the formation of benzyne using $\ce{Li/Hg}$. After this a Diels–Alder reaction takes place between furan and benzyne. The reaction mechanism would be as follows [[1](https://doi.org/10.4172/2153-2435.1000137)]:

> [image: Reaction Mechanism]

A more generalised form of this reaction, dealing with the conditions needed and the yield of reaction would be [[2](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-052349-1.00128-1)]:

> [image]

#### Reference

1. Shashidher, B.; Bajjuri, R.; Guguloath, V. Formation and Trapping of Benzyne. *Pharm Anal Acta* **2011**, 02 (07). DOI: [10.4172/2153-2435.1000137](https://doi.org/10.4172/2153-2435.1000137). ([PDF](https://www.longdom.org/open-access/formation-and-trapping-of-benzyne-2153-2435.1000137.pdf))
2. Comprehensive Organic Synthesis; Wolfgang Oppolzer; Université de Genève, Switzerland **1991**. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-052349-1.00128-1